# Problem in creating UIPageControl Programmatically?

Tags: iphone, uipagecontrol

// Init Page Control

```
UIPageControl *pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init]; 
pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(110,5,100,100); 
pageControl.numberOfPages = 2; 
pageControl.currentPage = 0; 
[self.view addSubview:pageControl];
```

I'm trying to create `UIPageControl` programmatically. I created new view based app. In which, i have written this code in ViewControllers `viewDidLoad`, but its not creating page control. When i see in console viewdidload is called many times.

Comment: Accept some answers and make sure that you added the page control to the correct view and is not behind any other view

Comment: Are you adding other views?  Start by commenting out all the code to add those and only add the pageControl.  If it still doesn't show up do other controls show up?

Answer (score 5):

LMAO with this one cause I just had the same problem :)
if you still got this problem or any one else will struggle with this try setting background colour simply like

```
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

the funny thing is that page controls' default colour settings make it difficult to notice on i.e. clear white view :)

Comment: Oh the nonwhite background does reveal the pagecontrol! I almost scratch head bald! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
[self.view addSubview:pageControl];
```

Before this code line add one more..

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:pageControl];
```

May this one help you..

Comment: Dude, Add one more line - [pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector() forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]..

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues with building views programmatically, and found that the best way is to build them once in the `Init` method, not in the `ViewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score 1):

if you are adding pageControl on white background it will not be visible. Add temporary border just to make sure it is there

```
    pageControl.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
```

If it is there, adjust tint colors

```
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.grayColor();
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor();
```

If it is not there, you are probably doing something wrong, it should be something like this:

```
    var pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRectMake(135, 230, 50, 20))
    pageControl.numberOfPages = 2;
    pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.grayColor();
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.greenColor();
    self.view.addSubview(pageControl);
```

Of course, you also need to link it with respective scrollView / pageView accordingly