# Problem in UIPageControl Creation

Tags: iphone, ios4

```
// Init Page Control

UIPageControl *pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];
pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(110,5,100,100); 
pageControl.numberOfPages = 2; 
pageControl.currentPage = 0; 
[self.view addSubview:pageControl];
```

I'm trying to create UIPageControl programmatically. I created new view based app. In which, i have written this code in ViewControllers viewDidLoad, but its not creating page control.
Because of [self.view addSubview:pageControl]; , its getting in infinite loop when application starts. why is it doing so? Is there any other option for this?

Comment: You are telling that viewDidLoad is called more then once?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem in creating UIPageControl Programmatically ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945969/problem-in-creating-uipagecontrol-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

move your code from `- (void)loadView` to `- (void)viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @sumit: If this answer has solved your problem, please accept it to indicate that to everybody else.  See: http://www.tinyurl.com/so-accept

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly the same thing and it works for me.
You can download my sample application [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?id3yn2irhbb8jvi)